# Total subscribed to hazelcast topic

Tags: java, hazelcast

I wanted to ask whether it is possible to get the total number of subscribed to a topic clusterwide with Hazelcast and how?

e.g.

```
ITopic topic = hazelcastInstance.getTopic("foo");

long totalSubscribed = topic.getSubscribed()
```

Thank you

Comment: This information is availably to the public. Also the topics are build on an internal eventing system that is shared with collection update evening system and near cache. On that level we don't see any more what kind of listener it.

Comment: not sure I understood what you said...

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `EventService` (part of the SPI) and call the following method:

```
Collection<EventRegistration> getRegistrations(String serviceName, String topic);
```

This should give you AFAIK insight in the number of listeners for a given topic.

Comment: interesting! How do you get hold of the `EventService`?

Comment: Either through reflection (yuk) or you need to let a class implement the ManagedService interface and register at an SPI service. It has a method 'init' that does a callback with the NodeEngine and there you can access the EventService. Check the following link for an example:

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/spi/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two approaches that can be used to find the number of topic subscribers.

1. Use the public API and get a list of the cluster `Member`s.
2. Use the Hazelcast SPI and provide a `ManagedService` that has access to the Hazelcast internal.

Both of these approaches works fine but the latter involves more coding and good knowledge of the SPI which is not as commonly used.

**Approach 1: Find the cluster `Member`s**
To find all the members that are (currently) part of the cluster you can use the following code:

```
final Set<Member> members = hazelcastInstance.getCluster().getMembers();
```

The above returns a `Set` of `Member` objects which are thoroughly described [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#cluster-utilities).

When starting a `Member` in the cluster you can set custom properties. This enables you to add your own logic for the `Member`s you start.

The following test case shows how this can be used:

```
public class TopicCounterTest {
    // Setup a hazelcast instance, bind the topic name as a custom property
    public HazelcastInstance setupHazelcastInstance(final String topicName) {
        // Set the custom property (in this case a boolean bound to the topic name)
        final MemberAttributeConfig topicMemberConfig = new MemberAttributeConfig();
        topicMemberConfig.setBooleanAttribute(topicName, true);

        final Config config = new Config();
        config.setMemberAttributeConfig(topicMemberConfig);
        config.setProperty("hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size", "1");

        // Create a HazelcastInstance
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }

    // Use a Java 8 stream to count all "Member"s that have the 
    // custom property set
    public long numberOfTopicListeners(
            final HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance, 
            final String topicName) {

        return hazelcastInstance.getCluster().getMembers().stream()
                .map(member -> {
                    final Map<String, Object> attributes = member.getAttributes();
                    return Optional.ofNullable(
                            member.getBooleanAttribute(topicName))
                            .orElse(false);
                })
                .count();
    }

    // Test case, start two instances and verify that they both are listeners on the topic
    @Test
    public void testTopicCounter() {
        final HazelcastInstance h1 = setupHazelcastInstance("testTopic");
        final HazelcastInstance h2 = setupHazelcastInstance("testTopic");

        Assert.assertEquals(2l, numberOfTopicListeners(h1, "testTopic"));
        Assert.assertEquals(2l, numberOfTopicListeners(h2, "testTopic"));
    }
}
```

**Approach 2: Use the Hazelcast SPI and provide a custom `ManagedService`**

The other approach requires you to use Hazelcast SPI (Service Provider Interface). It requires more code than the first approach and among other things you have to provide a `ManagedService`, register that service and then get hold of the `NodeEngine` via a callback. The `NodeEngine` has a handle to the `EventService` that you can then use to invoke the method `getRegistrations`.

One problem with the SPI-approach is that it requires SPI more code and you need to find a way to share the data between the managed service and your application. How to work with the SPI is described on the [Hazelcast website](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.3/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#user-defined-services).

**Recommendation**

My recommendation is to use the first approach. Make use of the public API:s and simply register a custom property that you can use to base your logic on. Simple, fast and safe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, because not all members will subscribe to my topic I finally ended up using an atomiclong again in hazelcast to hold the subscribers

Comment: @tbo That is pretty much exactly what I tried to explain! If not *all* members subscribes to the topic then some kind of attribute is required to distinguish them apart (as the `"I_LISTEN_TO_FOO_TOPIC"` above). However, if *all* members do listen to the topic you can simply count the members. I guess that one problem with the atomiclong approach is that if one of the members falls out of the cluster the counter will not drop (but the cluster-approach handles that).

Comment: In real world sometimes all members subscribe, but after some disaster - not all of them receive messages. Then only the SPI approach could give valid information.